# Swift 2 / XCode 7 - "EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2...)" when calling "ViewController().view" in another class

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, class, parameter-passing

[image: image of the runtime error im getting in my other class when trying to use tmpView]

why is this error happening and what can i do to fix/prevent in the future? thanks!

NOTE: my other class is set up as such:

```
class Other {

     //then all relevant funcs called 
    }
```

am i missing some basic setup information in order for this to run?

Comment: it seems the `Viewcontroller `does not have instance in that class, it throws an error. By the way, your question is not mature enough to provide a solution.

Comment: as mentioned, you can't reference a view for a view controller that has not yet been presented as you cannot ensure that its views aren't nil. if you need a particular view for reuses, make it its own class with its own initializer. then call it in this other class, and add it as a subview to self.view in your ViewController

Answer (score 0):

The formal explanation would be:

You're trying to access the `view` property before it was initialized. Another way to look at it is that you're trying to access the `view` property before it was loaded (in viewDidLoad).

Solution:

Depends what you're using that view for. I've never had to access another view controller's property like that. Consider exploring other strategies such as delegation, weak references to another controller, and passing variables in `prepareForSegue` if you need a reference from a view controller from another.

Comment: ok, but im not referencing a view controller from another view controller - just another class. is there a way to initialize ( i dont know what the right word is ) that class fast enough to make sure it doesnt fail?

Comment: i just dont want my viewcontroller class to get too filled up with code... it makes it hard to work

Comment: Let me know why you need to do this. I've never encountered a use case like this before, and if you give me more context I might be able to offer you a better solution.